# Auto fit height of parent container (display table)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve auto fit height of inner divs within a parent of `display: table`. Here is the markup I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="category">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="item">TEST</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="item">TEST</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="item">TEST</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
* { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body { 
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#content {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}

#category {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}

.item {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

In this example, There are three rows that equally distributed down the page. Within these rows there are inner divs called `.item`. These divs need to auto fit the height of their parent `.row`.

This works in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox. The only way I can make this work in Firefox is if I make the `.item` a `display: table` - but I don't want to do this because a plugin I am using won't work with that.

Is there any reason this isn't working in Firefox? Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Just created a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/wqw59/1/ (try this in Firefox and Chrome)

EDIT: I need to retain the main container markup and structure, as this is the skeleton for the entire site.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps you, but the following link shows there are some weird things that happen in firefox when applying certain types of positional styling(which I include height and width in my book) to tables. Although you arent actually using tables, it might do the same since your display is set to table.
[firefox position absolute inside a relative container issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267457/firefox-position-absolute-inside-a-relative-container-issue)

It helped me out alot. Something to consider is trying to put a span without a display edit in there and give it the width and height you need.

Something tells me that even though the problems are different, they are related in positioning issues since your issue is similar to what mine was and was fixed by changing it.

Comment: Cheers mate, that actually did point me in the right direction. Firefox seems to have this problem and using `position: absolute` fixes it. I would never have figured that out - so thanks again mate :) I will test it further and accept the answer if all good :)

Answer (score 0):

The three items have the same width and height the text is centered in the middle vertically and horizontally, elements remain this way on screen resize.

Parent horizintal : **[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/BAnU6/)** or parent vertical : **[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/BAnU6/1/)**

**Css :**

```
#category {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #DDD;
}
.row {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3333%
}
.item {
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFF;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.item div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.item span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.height {
    vmargin-top: 100%;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/BAnU6/2/

Comment: Hi, I don't think that would work since I need to have the three rows equally distributed down the page. Without using `table-row` that is going to be difficult to do.

Comment: Do you want the three rows combined to take up the whole height of the page no matter how high it is ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. So as I resize the page there should always be three rows visible on the page.

Comment: Added a an update, main container markup and structure have not been changed.