# Linear-gradient speech bubble working, then not working

Tags: css

I have a speech bubble (more like a selected menu indicator) working on a li in jsFiddle, then when I tried to pot it to my own page's li, it doesn't appear. Any idea why this is so?

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/22Bz3/4/

Broken fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/L6F5u/3/

Here is the .bubble css:

```
.bubble {
    position: relative;    
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(125,126,125,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
}

.bubble:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 25%;
    border-top: 15px solid blue;
    border-top-color: inherit; 
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent; 
}
```

**Edit:**
I found a workaround by using margin-left: 25px; It's strange since Firefox will use the page to position the triangle if you use percentage with margin, or any kind of left:value. 
Here is the fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/L6F5u/10/

Comment: In the non-working Fiddle, you have your `li` set to `display: table-cell;`. Remove this and the triangle appears. This messes up other things, but you can recreate the menu using floating or inline-block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you've set the border-color to inherit on your `li`'s pseudo element. This causes it to inherit the value used by this rule:

```
ul .selected {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Since the `a`'s are already explicitly set to white, there is no need for this. See: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6F5u/5/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, the fix works in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: @user3442612: Your syntax for the `linear-gradient()` is incorrect on the non-prefixed version. See: http://jsfiddle.net/L6F5u/9/

Comment: Ah, ok -- but the issue is still with the downward facing triangle. It seems Firefox is using the screen as the :after position instead of the element it is connected to.
I'm investigating this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267457/firefox-position-absolute-inside-a-relative-container-issue

Answer (score -1):

```
.bubble:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 25%;
    border-top: 15px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
```

}

Comment: this answer in fact works ***but*** it does not look like an answer.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you changed in the code and why?

Comment: :after pseudo was set to inherit a border-color. Since no border-color was defined on parent element, i don't know why is it there. I just set the color of the border to a bottom gradient color.